# Trouble using jackd with ALSA and an "AudioInjector Octo"

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa

I am attempting to run an AudioInjector Octo (a simple 8-channel audio hardware card) on a Raspberry Pi 4, running the Raspberry Lite OS.

My understanding is that ALSA manages AudioInjector - but that I also need jackd to send audio from my software (SuperCollider) to ALSA.

While ALSA seems to read the AudioInjector without trouble, I seemingly cannot get jackd to boot. I am new to all of this, so there may be many things I have not yet tried.

Namely, the following line of code causes my terminal prompt to freeze: jackd -d alsa -r 44100 -P hw:2

Any pointers would be a great help. Thanks!